# Can't change year as text format to date format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 1 column that only have year value but formatted as general. I really need that value but formated as date in year only. I have tried to change the format to date, use custom to yyyy and use =year(a1) function, but it's useless. any solution?

[image]

Comment: Only number value can't apply date formats. You first need to change it valid date value then apply date format. To change it date value you can enter `01/01/2011` then Or apply a function like `=Date(A1,1,1)` then you can apply any date related format.

Comment: It is better to enter the value as a date and then to format it as `yyyy`. if that is not your case, then you can create a date by converting the text into a date type as follow: `DATEVALUE("1/1/2008")`. You cannot format as date something that is not a date, it is a year for you but for Excel is a text or a number.

Answer (score 0):

Dates in Excel are integer values. First date Excel can recognize is `01/01/1900` which integer value is 1, number 2 would be `02/01/1900` and so on.

Number 2011 is 3rd July 1905 and because you are applying format `yyyy` Excel returns 1905.

You need first to do a proper date, not converting directly number 2011. So you need to type a date like `01/01/2011` (to be honest, any date from the 365 days of year 2011 would work but it is most usual to write on the first day of the year in these cases because you want just the year).

So you can do like this:

[image]

Formula in cell B1 is `=DATE(A1,1,1)` This will return always the first day of the year.

Now format B1 to `yyyy` and then it would be your expected output.

[image]

And just notice a fact: the date 01/01/2011 got an integer value of 40544 :)